# Problem of best practice with function return

Tags: javascript, function

I am new about programming. I have some difficulties to undurstand function.
So I done practice. But, I don't know why use **return**.

My code work.

In this exemple :
the function name is reverse.
I return in my function an array [1, 2, 5, 8].
Console.log a new array named reversed.

```
function reverse(array) {
  const reversed = [];
  for (i = array.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    reversed.push(array[i]);
  }
  console.log(reversed);
}
return reverse([1, 2, 5, 8]);
```

**
But why after validate exercice, it's say me false and send me this solution :**

```
function reverse(array) {
  const reversed = [];
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    reversed.push(array[i]);
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

Thanks : )

I googling and use chat GPT to teach me why use return in my case. But, nothing about I can understand.. I need your help.

Thank all.

Comment: You provide some input to the function (`array`) and expect the function to return an output (`reversed`). But that's just defining what the function should do, you also have to call the function.

Comment: Don't learn from ChatGPT, learn from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: w3schools is not the best place for learning.

Comment: `console.log` outputs the result in the console window, but that is not what you have been asked to do. Your function needs to return the result, not output it.

Comment: you need to move `return` inside of the function for letting the calling expression to know rhe result and btw, you need to declare `i`, because if not you get a global variable, or in strict mode, it raises an error.

Comment: @trincot thank that comment made more sense for me to understand. So we need to delete console.log after seen if function work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks:

- The names `reverse` and `reversed` are very similar which can lead to confusion. I see it happening in another answer and in your comments. `reverse` is defined as a function, and `reversed` is a local variable that references an array. They are completely different objects.
- In your code you have placed a `return` statement where it is not valid. A `return` statement can only occur inside a function body.
- `console.log(reversed)` will output the result in the console window, but that is not what the purpose is of the exercise. Although `console.log` is very useful while you are debugging your code, it is not equivalent to a *return value*. The caller of your function will get as return value what the function has returned with a `return` statement, not what `console.log` has output.
- Your code does not define `i` with `let` (or `var`) and so it is implicitly declared as a global variable. This is not good practice. Always define variables explicitly.
- Your code *calls* the `reverse` function. This is what you typically would do to *test* your function, but in code challenges, this call is typically made by the person or framework that tests your implementation. And those tests will call it more than once, with different arrays as argument, often including boundary cases, like an empty array, or a very large array.

So when you debug code, you would call the function and print the value that it *returns*, like so:

```js
function reverse(array) {
  const reversed = [];
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    reversed.push(array[i]);
  }
  return reversed;
}

let result = reverse([1,2,3,4]);
console.log(result); // Should be [4,3,2,1]
result = reverse([1]);
console.log(result); // Should be [1]
result = reverse([]);
console.log(result); // Should be []
result = reverse(reverse([1,2,3,4])); // Reversing the result!
console.log(result); // Should be [1,2,3,4]
```

Maybe I should also mention that `reverse` is also a native method available for arrays. It will reverse the array itself instead of creating a new array (like above). If the purpose is to always create a new array, you can still make use of it: first create a copy of the given array, reverse the copy and return that:

```js
function reverse(array) {
  // The spread syntax creates a copy, and reverse is applied on the copy
  return [...array].reverse(); 
}

let result = reverse([1,2,3,4]);
console.log(result); // Should be [4,3,2,1]
result = reverse([1]);
console.log(result); // Should be [1]
result = reverse([]);
console.log(result); // Should be []
result = reverse(reverse([1,2,3,4])); // Reversing the result!
console.log(result); // Should be [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: You're answer will help more than one guy. Thank, it's like a tutorial. I'll continues to practice. I noticed also the second part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `reversed` is defined inside the function body so it can only be accessed from inside of the function. In your code you tried to access the variable from outside of the function. `return` keyword is used inside the function to return a value, using `return` outside the function has no effect.

Comment: Thank for answer, How function will know what value will return ? In my case I return reverse([1, 2, 5, 8]); And it's send me [8, 5, 2, 1] but in second case there is no value.